# Is the icon for this site supposed to be "art"?

Tags: support

I just noticed that the icon on the tabs for this site say "art," whereas I would have expected something like "clg" or "col" or something like that.  Is this intentional, or is it a bug?

Comment: I assumed the icon is a short form of `artificial languages`.

Comment: I can I jut say that I came specifically here because it confused me :/ . Like honestly, this seems to be a horribly chosen name... even if it's just "temporary".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`art` — the ISO 639-5 code for constructed languages and prefix code for conlangs not assigned a code.

*ref. [List of ISO 639-5 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-5_codes)*

Comment: That explains why it's lowercase and not small caps like all the others.

Comment: Very *art*istic. Who gets the credit for that? :-)